# How to increase disk space on a physical Ubuntu installation with only root partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

My Ubuntu 19.04 is installed on a 40GB partition of a 1TB hard drive, and I mounted that disk to / partition.

Now the disk space is very low, and I want to add more space to it. If I split the rest of the hard drive and create a new 100GB EXT4 partition, how do I utilize that in my Ubuntu?

Comment: Don't move the start point of / but you can expand its size if you can make vacant space available behind it. See https://gparted.org/ which can be used if you boot from a LiveUSB. Until then, BleachBit https://www.bleachbit.org/ can help you reduce cruft in your system. It's Open Source, and works on Linux as well as Windows.

Comment: Can you open a terminal and provide the output of "sudo vgs; sudo lvs" - This will show if you are using  LVM. If you are you can simply and easily grow your root partition. (If not, you can still do this, but its a lot harder)